# Html2Pdf -Codeigniter -Image not loading

Tags: php, codeigniter, html2pdf

I am using HTML2PDF Library for codeigniter

See:https://github.com/aiwmedia/HTML2PDF-CI
My problem is i am unable to load images using  tag. Instead of image it always shows alt attribute. Tried giving the full path and relative path.

View:

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/uploads/pdf_images/1.jpg" alt="<?php echo base_url(); ?>uploads/pdf_images/1.jpg"/>
```

Controller:

```
$this->load->library('html2pdf');
$this->html2pdf->folder(APPPATH."third_party/samples/");
$file_name=$this->random_string(7);
$this->html2pdf->filename($file_name.'.pdf');
$this->html2pdf->paper('a4', 'portrait');
//$this->html2pdf->html($this->load->view('pdfcouple',$data,true));
if($user_details_arr[0]->is_married)
{
    $content=$this->load->view('pdfcouple', $data, true);
}
$this->html2pdf->html($content);
$this->html2pdf->create('save');
```

Comment: Have you checked, that baseurl has a subfolder named uploads? You could also try to base64-encode the image and embed the full data, not just the location.

Comment: baseurl has got subfolder called uploads. Let me check for other solution suggested.

Comment: Have you tried with the base64 content, alias `src="data:image/jpg;base64,{$base64contentofyourimage}"`?

Comment: Tried :
<?php
$path = base_url() .'/uploads/pdf_images/1.jpg';
$type = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$data = file_get_contents($path);
$base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);
?>
<img src="<?php echo $base64; ?>"/>
Not working

Comment: please try it with `<img src="<?php $path = base_url() .'/uploads/pdf_images/1.jpg'; $type = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); $data = file_get_contents($path); echo 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data); ?>"></img>`

Comment: Not working , i tried loading google images , but images or backround images are not loading

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157702/discussion-between-blesson-christy-and-cramopy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue by editing dompdf_config.custom.inc.php

uncommented

```
define("DOMPDF_ENABLE_REMOTE", true);
```

Now the images are loading inside pdf. Thanks for the support.