# could not load image in html2pdf in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, html2pdf

I am trying to create a pdf file from html in my codeigniter project. The html file contains an image but it will not load in the pdf. I am using html2pdf library and here is my code.

**example.php :**

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/images/logo.jpg" alt="BulkSMS">
```

I am pasting only the `<img>` tag here, because it is a large file.

**and here is my controller function**

```
public function htmlToPdf($data) {

    $this->html2pdf->folder(PURCHASE_INVOICE_PATH);
    $fileName = $data['invoiceNumber'].'.pdf';
    $this->html2pdf->filename($fileName);

    $this->html2pdf->paper('a4', 'portrait');

    $content = $this->load->view('templates/example', '', true);
    //Load html view
    $this->html2pdf->html($content);
    $this->html2pdf->create('save');  
    return $fileName;
}
```

I tried to change path of image to full path and type of image from png to jpg. But still it not showing

Comment: Have you try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46988041/html2pdf-codeigniter-image-not-loading ?

Comment: @HastaDhana Thank you. It solved my issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is happening becuase of CORS. Uncomment The following line from the dompdf_config.inc.php file located in application/libraries/dompdf folder.

```
define("DOMPDF_ENABLE_REMOTE", true);
```